# Scanning variables from a CSV text file

Tags: java

Hi, I'm struggling to scan and assign variables from a CSV text file, the error below is what I get at run-time and have no idea what's going wrong

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException</p>
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)</p>
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)</p>

public Moves(String role) throws FileNotFoundException{

    //Concatenate filename
    File file = new File("/moves/" + role + "Moves");
    //Declare and initialise scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("/moves/" + role + "Moves");
    //Loops through move file, assign variables from file
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        name       = scanner.next().trim();
        damageType = scanner.next().trim();
        minDamage  = scanner.nextInt();
        maxDamage  = scanner.nextInt();
        minHeal    = scanner.nextInt();
        maxHeal    = scanner.nextInt();
        recurringDamage = scanner.nextInt();
        damageCounter   = scanner.nextInt();
        aoeSize         = scanner.nextInt();
        description     = scanner.next().trim();
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(damageType);
        System.out.println(minDamage);
        System.out.println(maxDamage);
        System.out.println(minHeal);
        System.out.println(maxHeal);
        System.out.println(recurringDamage);
        System.out.println(damageCounter);
        System.out.println(aoeSize);
        System.out.println(description);
    }
    scanner.close();    
}
```

Comment: You have a `System.out` for every time the function goes through, can you check on which `scanner.next()`call it fails on by checking which is the last parameter it prints out to the console? Where do you initialize the variables?

Comment: Just do yourself a favor and use one of the many CSV parser frameworks available.

Comment: I initialize them in the constructor, it fails on the first line

Answer (score 0):

Pass 'file' argument to scanner.

```
    File file = new File("/moves/" + role + "Moves");
    //Declare and initialise scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file );
```